# How to change image text in Redactor

Tags: javascript, redactor, redactor.js

I want to change the image text which is 'Insert image' to 'Insert up to 3 images' I am trying to do it via the redactor plugin rather than overwriting with jquery.

I found the text in redactor js under lang but I don't want to edit the source either.

```
    // lang
    langs: {
        en: {
            image: 'Insert Image',
```

I found a way to change the language but not any properties of the lang, here
https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/languages/

Any assistance is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
langs: {
        en: {
            image: 'Insert up to 3 images'
            }
        }
```

To your Redactor instance. Note it is `langs` and not `lang` that's waht got me.